# Typescript 4.5 excessive stack depth comparing types

Tags: typescript

TS 4.5 released a feature of [tail recursive evaluation of conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45711), and I have this code.

```js
type TupleOfLength<Len extends number, Arr extends any[] = []> = 
  Arr["length"] extends Len ? Arr : TupleOfLength<Len, [...Arr, Arr["length"]]>;

// error: Excessive stack depth comparing types 'number' and 'keyof TupleOfLength<T["length"], []>'
type RandomIndex<T extends any[]> = Array<TupleOfLength<T["length"]>[number]>;

// can infer correct type, which is (0 | 1 | 2)[]
type RandomIndexArr = RandomIndex<["smile", "hey", "goodbye"]>;
// What I want is that having a tuple, and infer an array of tuple indexes
```

I searched for a while, and I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168740/typescript-recursive-type-with-particular-depth) helpful, but in that case, the recursion have a clear base case, while in my case, `Len` may be of any length, and `Len` is quite similar to `Depth` of that question, how can I add another `Depth` generic parameter in my type.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgVwgGygeQGYBkoDsDmIAFgDw64xQAeIeAJgM4y4IC2ARlAE4A0MAgly6Ua9JgENcYANoBdGAF4YcgHyKYwGAKHSARKgLFd86rVyMY5GAH5twgFzwkqTOUKlyfaQDpfg3nZ6Bu7GsioA3MDAAPTRlEIA9lyOAKJUAMZQDAwAlgBusAwg4ukA1jB0UBDEMOkJrBDiXDkEMODQTADkLBzcnTCSdDCdpVBgCRhOKOjYeO4kcEFzRrJeYZ2gkLAASoP1AJLm1AsiZhaSMmHq-uJgC84zbsQLS4ZExirSPZxcYZExcXSkhgLQw3FqSS4UHSIDaW020Bgu3MByOVH86mRdFRlSoJD0DFYOVQuj4uiIY1JMF0%20ASCTo7DAUA%204SAA)

Comment: I suppose the reason TS yelled at me is that `T["length"]` in `RandomIndex` may be too long.

Comment: Sometimes the compiler evaluates circular types too eagerly; you can often *defer* this with a distributive conditional type, so if `type Foo<X> = Bar<X, Y, Z>` hits a stack limit, sometimes `type Foo<X> = X extends any ? Bar<X, Y, Z> : never` will not. Also, do you really need truly *numeric* indices for a tuple type? The compiler tends to represent these naturally as string literal versions like `"0"`, and those types behave quite similarly for indexing.  If you would accept `("0"|"1"|"2")[]` instead of `(0|1|2)[]`, that doesn't require recursion. [See here](//tsplay.dev/NaY79N).

Comment: I want to understand the use case because a [recent feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47141) to turn string literals to numeric literals was declined, and this here would seem to be a justification for such a feature.  `StringToNumber<Exclude<T, keyof any[]>>` would be an easy way to turn `["x","y","z"]` into `0|1|2`.  But I don't know if your use case really requires this.

Comment: If you want to see any of this written up as an answer, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz I have posted the use case as an answer, looking forward to your insight

Comment: And doesn't [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVgxnm) work for your use case just as well?  If you're just using `0|1|2` as an index to a tuple, you can use `"0"|"1"|"2"` instead and it just works.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a lot, I tend to overthink too much, the answer has been updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The use case:

```js
type TupleOfLength<Len extends number, Arr extends any[] = []> = 
  Arr["length"] extends Len ? Arr : TupleOfLength<Len, [...Arr, Arr["length"]]>;

// error: Excessive stack depth comparing types 'number' and 'keyof TupleOfLength<T["length"], []>'
type RandomIndex<T extends any[]> = TupleOfLength<T["length"]>[number];

// can infer correct type, which is 0 | 1 | 2
type RandomIndexRes = RandomIndex<["smile", "hey", "goodbye"]>;

class Father {}
class Son extends Father {}
class AnotherSon extends Father {}

class Test<T extends Father[]> {
  anotherClasses!: T;
  stuffNeedBindingToAnotherClassBasedOnIndex = ["hey", "goodbye", "smile", "punch"];

  setAnotherClasses(...args: T): Array<RandomIndex<T>> {
    this.anotherClasses = args;

    /*
    Here I want
    hey => AnotherSon
    goodbye => Father
    smile => Son
    punch => AnotherSon 
    */
    return [2, 0, 1, 2] as Array<RandomIndex<T>>;
  }

  combine() {
    // @ts-ignore
    const order = this.setAnotherClasses(new Father(), new Son(), new AnotherSon());
    Test.zip(order.map(i => this.anotherClasses[i]), this.stuffNeedBindingToAnotherClassBasedOnIndex);
  }

  // for sake of integrity, I gave the full function body of zip in my project
  // Though silly here, the real scenario is way more complex that `zip` is quite useful 
  static *zip<T extends Iterable<unknown>[]>(...iterables: T) {
      type IterableType<T> = T extends Iterable<infer U> ? U : never;
      type TransformIterableType<T extends Iterable<unknown>[]> = {
          [K in keyof T]: IterableType<T[K]>;
      };

      const iterators = iterables.map((i) => i[Symbol.iterator]());
      while (1) {
          const results = iterators.map((iter) => iter.next());
          if (results.some((res) => res.done)) return;
          yield results.map((res) => res.value) as TransformIterableType<T>;
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks to @jcalz, the answer is simple, I overthought too much.

```js
type ToNumber<T, R extends any[] = []> =
    T extends `${R['length']}` ? R['length'] : ToNumber<T, [1, ...R]>;
type RandomStringIndex<T extends unknown[]> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[]>;
type RandomNumericIndex<T extends unknown[]> = ToNumber<RandomStringIndex<T>>;

// can infer correct type, which is 0 | 1 | 2
type RandomNumericIndexRes = RandomNumericIndex<["hello", "bye", "smile"]>;
```